# JWT SOBO for DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I finally got JWT authorization working (both token access + login) using the C# SDK API.  However I'm trying to figure out how SOBO works using JWT.  I'm reading this [help here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo) and it shows the legacy way (username and email).  I'm assuming the process is similar for JWT but I am not sure how to go about it, especially if requiring the SOBO's integrator key (for which I don't have).  This [help here](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-using-the-oauth-jwt-flow/) says it is possible with JWT OAuth, but doesn't explain how.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got JWT worked by having that user's consent (either thru Auth Grant or using Admin consent). Now in legacy SOBO you used to pass SOBO user's email or userId in the Auth header, in same way while generating a token for that user using JWT you need that user's consent (if not using Admin consent) and that user's userId (sub in the JWT payload). Once you have these two important items then you can create a JWT for any user in the DocuSign. This way SOBO is replaced with more secure JWT.

Comment: I'm using org admin consent.  When I granted consent to myself, I had to pass in the client id (integrator key).  If I had to grant consent for another user the same way, the problem is I don't have access to their integrator key.  Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Also, say that user grants consent all by themselves using that url and passing in their integrator key.  Now to use SOBO with OAuth JWT, what do I need to do.  I login as myself and get an account Id / access token.  Do I stick that user's api username (non-integrator key) or email somewhere in the body?  I need an example of this since I don't see it documented anywhere on the DocuSign site.  Thanks Amit!

Comment: With Admin Consent, you can generate JWT for any user in your account or Organization, you just need that user's userId. Also IntegratorKey is linked to an account, not to a user. So, if you have given consent to an IntegratorKey in your Organization for Admin Consent then you can use same IntegratorKey for getting JWT for another user in your account.

Comment: With Admin Consent, there is no concept of URL. Giving consent via URL (Authorization Code Grant) is needed only for User consent, but you mentioned that you are using Admin consent so you should not use URL based consent.

Comment: Hmm I had to do this to get consent:  https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=[myintegratorkey]&redirect_uri=https://docusign.com

Comment: If what you're saying is the case, then all I really need to SOBO is the user's id and the same integrator key correct?  If so is it really SOBO in the general sense since all I need to do is login with any user id along with the same integrator key?  I'll give it a shot though.

Comment: If you are using https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=[myintegratorkey]&redirect_uri=https://docusign.com, then it is called `User Consent` not `Admin Consent`. But you got it, you need other user's credentials and its userId and you can use same integratorKey to create a JWT for another user.

Comment: BTW, if what i did was user consent, where do I set for admin consent?

Comment: Hey Amit, I'm getting a "consent required" when trying to SOBO as another user.  How do I activate admin consent?  We have org admin BTW.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161756/discussion-between-los-morales-and-amit-k-bist).

Comment: Yes needed to figure out admin consent. finally got that working and everything amit mentioned above is correct!  Thanks!