# Docusign - Can We use personal plan, and be able to get consent from external users for SOBO?

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

We are building a project, where the admin consent is required.

Since it seems that to get consent from an external user for SOBO using JWT. We will require an admin consent as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929681/jwt-sobo-for-docusign-api) and [here](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-external/).

But to access it, we have to contact support and enable it in sandbox as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293460/docusign-sandbox-redirect-uri-not-working)

When this will go in production, will this work in the [Personal API Plan](https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing) or the [starter pack](https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing/api-plans-old)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [get consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/) from any user in any plan without using admin consent.
It's simply called Individual Consent and all you have to do is take the user to a URL that looks like this:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=<YOUR_IK>&redirect_uri=https://client.example.com/callback
```

Comment: But won't this work in case when everything is happening in frontend. If someone wants to implement SOBO using JWT, Won't they require admin consent?

Comment: I'm able to give my own consent with the same developer account. But If I try a different user email, after getting consent I received USER_NOT_FOUND. When trying to retrieve the GUIID of the user in the backend.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47929681/jwt-sobo-for-docusign-api

The comments here mention about using admin consent, for SOBO.

Comment: Admin consent is better. but does require your customer to set up an organization as you noted.

Comment: You can solve the user not found error by using the correct accountId when making the API call.